# Edit Button on Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have a container with a hover overlay that darkens the entire container. I wish to show an edit button alongside the overlay right in the middle.

```css
.service-inner {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pale-grey;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.service-inner:hover > .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-inner">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please provide a full sample code along with HTML codes

Comment: just a random though, can that button have `display:none` by default and `display:inline-block` on hover??

Comment: @NoobEditor this will not work since due to display:none there is no component. So hove event will never be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `div class="button"` on the same level as your overlay and give it the same positioning properties but a higher `z-index`, then activate it on hover the same as your `overlay` element.

```css
.button {
    display:none;
}

.container:hover > .button{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    width:20%;
    left: 40%;
    background-color: green;
    color:black;
    z-index: 200;
}
```